# best padding scheme for RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, padding

So i came across three padding scheme for RSA: PKCS1, PSS and OAEP.
My intention here is to encrypt a file using AES key. then, encrypt the AES key with
the RSA key and save the encrypted AES key along with the encrypted file.
My question is which one of the padding schemes above best suits my purpose.
Needless to say security is top priority for me and using compromised algorithm is off the table.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PKCS#1](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf) contains 4 padding schemes, of which only 2 are suitable for encryption, but only of small data blocks (like up to hundred bytes): the modern [RSAES-OAEP](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=16), and the obsolete [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=23) (which drawbacks include being harder to guard against decryption oracle attacks on the padding). PSS, aka [RSASSA-PSS](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=27), is strictly for signature.

For comfortable security, [AES-GCM-SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8452) with a random 256-bit key encrypted per RSA-4096 using RSAES-OAEP with SHA-512 and MGF1 using SHA-512, would tick all the boxes (on crypto algorithm choices, ignoring implementation isssues) except resistance to hypothetical quantum computers usable for cryptanalysis. The modern baseline would be RSA-2048 using RSAES-OAEP with SHA-256 and MGF1 using SHA-256.