# Is it safe to use RSA multiple times

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, symmetric

Assuming I have multiple symmetric keys on specific machine(more than 10000 probably),
can I use the same rsa key to encrypt all of those keys?
I'm a bit concerned from a situation where multiple encrypted keys will have similar pattern
and will leak data about the original ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be concerned if you use PKCS#1 v2 encryption padding - the OAEP.

OAEP, the Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding guarantees that even the slightest difference in *raw* plaintext (in your case, your symmetric keys) will result in huge difference in *padded* plaintext.

Comment: I thought PKCS and OAEP are different padding algorithms.Also, is OAEP secure enough(math wise)

Comment: @user83734: PKCS (Public Key Cryptography Standards) is a collection of specifications that used to be at the website of RSA Security/Labs. It ended at EMC, and got lost in a website revamping. Some of it is now in RFCs. PKCS#1 specifies RSA keys, encryption and signature. As I just [wrote](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84106/555), PKCS#1v2[.2] contains two RSA encryption paddings, named RSAES-OAEP (aka `[RSA-]OAEP` or `PKCS[#]1[ ]v2[[.]1|2][ OAEP][ encryption][ padding]`), and an old one named RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 (aka `PKCS[[#]1[[ ]v1[.[5]]]][ original|old][ encryption][ padding]`).

Comment: Although a padding parameter or option in software _named_ 'pcks1' or just 'pkcs' usually was chosen before that name became ambiguous, i.e. before pkcs1v2, and not changed after, and thus refers to the old scheme (RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5). E.g. OpenSSL comandline `rsautl -pkcs` and Java 'transform' `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` both dating to the early 1990s.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** By any modern definition of a secure cipher, it can safely be used many times with the same key (the OTP can't safely reuse its pad/key, thus is not a proper cipher).

Leaving a lot of formalism aside, [RSAES-OAEP](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=16) of PKCS#1v2.2 is a secure asymmetric cipher, which security is proven (to some degree, under some hypothesis including perfect implementation) from the combination of:

- The assumed security of the hash that it uses internally.
- The assumed hardness of the RSA problem: for proper choice of key $(N,e,d)$, finding $m$ that was chosen at random in $[0,N)$ given $m^e\bmod N$.

There's a convoluted history to this result. Unless I missed a later development, the tightest proof is Eiichiro Fujisaki, Tatsuaki Okamoto, David Pointcheval and Jacques Stern's [*RSA-OAEP is Secure under the RSA Assumption*](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/2004_joc.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-002-0204-y). Abstract:

> Recently Victor Shoup noted that there is a gap in the widely believed security result of OAEP against adaptive chosen-ciphertext attacks. Moreover, he showed that, presumably, OAEP cannot be proven secure from the one-wayness of the underlying trapdoor permutation. This paper establishes another result on the security of OAEP. It proves that OAEP offers semantic security against adaptive chosen-ciphertext attacks, in the random oracle model, under the partial-domain one-wayness of the underlying permutation. Therefore, this uses a formally stronger assumption. Nevertheless, since partial-domain one-wayness of the RSA function is equivalent to its (full-domain) onewayness, it follows that the security of RSA-OAEP can actually be proven under the sole RSA assumption, although the reduction is not tight.